# Compile a project with C and C++ files separately using gcc and g++?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile, g++

I have a project that contains C and C++ files and I created a Makefile to compile this project.

Is it possible to have a Makefile that will "separate" the C and C++ files, the C files will be compile with gcc and the C++ files with g++ and create one binary ?

This is the Makefile I created:

```
TECHAUDIO_ROOT = ../../../../../../..
TECHAUDIO_GENERIC = $(TECHAUDIO_ROOT)/Generic
TECHAUDIO_MALLOC_3DSL = $(TECHAUDIO_ROOT)/Tools/Malloc_3DSL
TECHAUDIO_SIGPROC_COMMON_SRC = ../../../../SignalProcessing/RefFT/Common/src
TECHAUDIO_SIGPROC_SRC = ../../../../SignalProcessing/RefFT/Float/src
TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_SRC = ../../../RefFT/Float/src
TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_COMMON_SRC = ../../../RefFT/Common/src/API

INCLUDES += -I$(TECHAUDIO_GENERIC)/Common/Include \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_GENERIC)/X86/Include \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_MALLOC_3DSL)/RefFT/Common/Include \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_SIGPROC_COMMON_SRC) \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_SIGPROC_SRC)/Math \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_SIGPROC_SRC)/Transform \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_SIGPROC_SRC)/Filter \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_SIGPROC_SRC)/Vector \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_SIGPROC_SRC)/SSTP \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_SRC)/API \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_COMMON_SRC) \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_SRC)

SRCS =      $(TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_SRC)/LIMITOR_main_32f.c \
            $(TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_SRC)/API/LIMITOR_API_32f.c \
            $(TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_SRC)/API/LIMITOR_API_coordinate_32f.c

SRCSCPP =   $(TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_SRC)/Test/LIMITOR_TEST_example_32f.cpp
#           $(TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_SRC)/VST/LIMITOR_VST_audioEffect_32f.cpp \                                                                                                      
#           $(TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_SRC)/VST/LIMITOR_VST_main_32f.cpp                                                                                                               

NAME = Bonjour

CC = gcc

CPP = g++

CFLAGS += $(INCLUDES)
CFLAGS += -D_X86_GCC_4_1_1_TARGET_
#CFLAGS +=-D_X86_VC8_TARGET_                                                                                                                                                        
RM = rm -f

OBJ= $(SRCS:.c=.o)

OBJCPP= $(SRCSCPP:.cpp=.o)

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $(NAME) -lm
         $(OBJCPP)
        $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJCPP) -o $(NAME) -lm

clean:
        $(RM) $(OBJ) $(OBJCPP)

fclean: clean
        $(RM) $(NAME)
re: fclean all
```

**EDIT**

Below is an updated version of the Makefile:

```
TECHAUDIO_ROOT = ../../../../../../..
TECHAUDIO_GENERIC = $(TECHAUDIO_ROOT)/Generic
TECHAUDIO_MALLOC_3DSL = $(TECHAUDIO_ROOT)/Tools/Malloc_3DSL
TECHAUDIO_SIGPROC_COMMON_SRC = ../../../../SignalProcessing/RefFT/Common/src
TECHAUDIO_SIGPROC_SRC = ../../../../SignalProcessing/RefFT/Float/src
TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_SRC = ../../../RefFT/Float/src
TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_COMMON_SRC = ../../../RefFT/Common/src/API

INCLUDES += -I$(TECHAUDIO_GENERIC)/Common/Include \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_GENERIC)/X86/Include \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_MALLOC_3DSL)/RefFT/Common/Include \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_SIGPROC_COMMON_SRC) \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_SIGPROC_SRC)/Math \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_SIGPROC_SRC)/Transform \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_SIGPROC_SRC)/Filter \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_SIGPROC_SRC)/Vector \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_SIGPROC_SRC)/SSTP \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_SRC)/API \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_COMMON_SRC) \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_SRC)

 SRCS =     $(TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_SRC)/LIMITOR_main_32f.c \
            $(TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_SRC)/API/LIMITOR_API_32f.c \
            $(TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_SRC)/API/LIMITOR_API_coordinate_32f.c

SRCSCPP =   $(TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_SRC)/Test/LIMITOR_TEST_example_32f.cpp
#           $(TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_SRC)/VST/LIMITOR_VST_audioEffect_32f.cpp \                                                                                                      
#           $(TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_SRC)/VST/LIMITOR_VST_main_32f.cpp                                                                                                               

NAME = Bonjour

CC = gcc

CPP = g++

CFLAGS += $(INCLUDES)
CFLAGS += -D_X86_GCC_4_1_1_TARGET_
#CFLAGS +=-D_X86_VC8_TARGET_                                                                                                                                                        

RM = rm -f

OBJ= $(SRCS:.c=.o)

OBJCPP= $(SRCSCPP:.cpp=.o)

%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $<

%.o: %.cpp
        $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) $<

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJ) $(OBJCPP)
           $(LD)  $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
         $(RM) $(OBJ) $(OBJCPP)

fclean: clean
        $(RM) $(NAME)
re: fclean all
```

These are the errors I receive when I execute `make`:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): réadressage 20 a un index de symbole 13 invalide
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): réadressage 21 a un index de symbole 22 invalide
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): réadressage 0 a un index de symbole 2 invalide
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: dans la fonction « _start »:
(.text+0x18): référence indéfinie vers « main »
/tmp/ccvLa3z6.o: dans la fonction « LIMITOR_3DSL_getStatusSize_32f »:
LIMITOR_main_32f.c:(.text+0x1e): référence indéfinie vers « MALLOC_3DSL_compute_memory_size_align_heap »
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these rules:

```
%.o: %.c
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $<

%.o: %.cpp
     $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) $<
```

And changing your main line to:

```
$(NAME): $(OBJ) $(OBJCPP)
     $(LD)  $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

---

EDIT:

Here is an attempt to integrate this in your code. I did not run this, though.

```
TECHAUDIO_ROOT = ../../../../../../..
TECHAUDIO_GENERIC = $(TECHAUDIO_ROOT)/Generic
TECHAUDIO_MALLOC_3DSL = $(TECHAUDIO_ROOT)/Tools/Malloc_3DSL
TECHAUDIO_SIGPROC_COMMON_SRC = ../../../../SignalProcessing/RefFT/Common/src
TECHAUDIO_SIGPROC_SRC = ../../../../SignalProcessing/RefFT/Float/src
TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_SRC = ../../../RefFT/Float/src
TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_COMMON_SRC = ../../../RefFT/Common/src/API

INCLUDES += -I$(TECHAUDIO_GENERIC)/Common/Include \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_GENERIC)/X86/Include \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_MALLOC_3DSL)/RefFT/Common/Include \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_SIGPROC_COMMON_SRC) \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_SIGPROC_SRC)/Math \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_SIGPROC_SRC)/Transform \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_SIGPROC_SRC)/Filter \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_SIGPROC_SRC)/Vector \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_SIGPROC_SRC)/SSTP \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_SRC)/API \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_COMMON_SRC) \
            -I$(TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_SRC)

 SRCS =     $(TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_SRC)/LIMITOR_main_32f.c \
            $(TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_SRC)/API/LIMITOR_API_32f.c \
            $(TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_SRC)/API/LIMITOR_API_coordinate_32f.c

SRCSCPP =   $(TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_SRC)/Test/LIMITOR_TEST_example_32f.cpp
#           $(TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_SRC)/VST/LIMITOR_VST_audioEffect_32f.cpp \                                                                                                      
#           $(TECHAUDIO_LIMOTOR_SRC)/VST/LIMITOR_VST_main_32f.cpp                                                                                                               

NAME = Bonjour

CC = gcc -c
CPP = g++ -c
LD = g++ -o

CFLAGS += $(INCLUDES)
CFLAGS += -D_X86_GCC_4_1_1_TARGET_
#CFLAGS +=-D_X86_VC8_TARGET_                                                                                                                                                        

RM = rm -f

OBJ= $(SRCS:.c=.o)

OBJCPP= $(SRCSCPP:.cpp=.o)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CPP) $< -o $@  $(CFLAGS)

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJ) $(OBJCPP)
    $(LD) $@  $^ -lm

clean:
         $(RM) $(OBJ) $(OBJCPP)

fclean: clean
    $(RM) $(NAME)

re: fclean all
```

Comment: I did it and when I compile I have no reference on the "main". The main is in the c++ file `LIMITOR_TEST_example_32f.cpp`

Comment: Did it compile all the files? Do you see all the .o files? What I wrote there is  obviously not usable since you didn't define LD, but the principle should be right. Could you give the full code after you've added this?

Comment: No it stop on the first file. But it might be for a different reason I update qustion and show the logs

Comment: @leykan LD is a common name for the linker program, in this case it is GCC as well. I added a full source that *could* work, but didn't run it.

Comment: Thx it works !  the only thing is that I don't understand this Makefile I'm gona do some research on the gramar thx

Comment: I'll add some explanations to it in a few hours, too busy at the moment.